# StructureMap and Project Dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, structuremap3

Suppose I have the following structure in my C# solution:

```
ServiceProject
-- IBusinessLogic.cs
-- Service.cs

BusinessLogicProject
-- IRepository.cs
-- BusinessLogic.cs

RepositoryProject
-- Repository.cs
```

In this case, I have `BusinessLogicProject` references `ServiceProject` (because `BusinessLogic` implements `IBusinessLogic`) and `RepositoryProject` references `BusinessLogic` (for a similar reason).

Suppose that I want to add `StructureMap` and use IoC container to register types and classes. It appears to me that this container will depend on interfaces--and hence should reference those projects, and it appears that all the projects need to reference this container--hence every project will depend on the container. How can I change this structure without introducing circular dependency?

Comment: Why would all project reference the container?

Comment: To resolve the types? The BusinessLogic will need a repository. So it will need the container to resolve the type of the repository it needs. Is there a way to hide that?

Comment: If your classes depend on the container to resolve a dependency, you're misapplying the IoC principle. It sounds like you're using the Service Locator anti-pattern. Your classes should receive their dependencies via constructor injection, and your composition root should be responsible for managing the dependency chain.